# Grails command object fails to wire properly for delete using Restangular

Tags: angularjs, grails, restangular

I am trying to create a RESTish service using grails. I have the following...

```
def delete(Question q){
    def text = request.reader.text;
    def slurper = new JsonSlurper();
    def result = slurper.parseText(text)
    println "Request body is ${text} but the parsed version has a text of ${q.text} whereas the slurper gives me ${result as JSON}"
    render noteService.delete(result.key)
}
```

This gives me an output of...

```
Request body is {"text":"Test Text","desc":"Test Desc","voteCount":0,"key":0} but the parsed version has a text of null whereas the slurper gives me {"desc":"Test Desc","key":0,"text":"Test Text","voteCount":0}
```

Why is this not wiring properly? The command object looks as follows...

```
@Validateable
class Question {
    Integer key
    String text
    String desc
    Integer voteCount
}
```

Is the delete request a GET under the hood or something? Is it expecting some other format?

**Update**

The create (POST) request is wiring fine which leads me to believe it is something with the differance between the Restangular call and what grails is expecting (So I think my request type guess might be right). My restangular code is simply...

```
this.delete = function(index) {
    var questionToUpdate = _this.questions[index];
    questionToUpdate.remove();
}
```

Also appears to fail with update (put) as well

Grails version is 2.4.3

Comment: The data binding should not be any different for a POST request vs. a GET request unless `Question` is a domain class.  Since it is marked with `@Validateable` I expect that it is not a domain class.  Is that correct?

Comment: That is correct, in fact this whole project isn't using a DB just a ConcurrentHashMap. The full project can be found here... https://github.com/jrgleason/ngGrails

Comment: What steps are required to run that app and reproduce the behavior in question?

Comment: Looks like you figured it out. You need to run npm install (assuming you have node + grunt) then grails run-app should be fine. Need to finish the readme

Comment: "Looks like you figured it out." - No, I didn't.  It isn't clear from looking at the running app how to interact with it to recreate your problem.

Comment: Do you at least have the application running? If so the easiest way to recreate what I am doing is to grab an app like Postman for chrome. Then try adding the command object to the controller (I haven't checked that in because it would break it but see the original question for the code). Then use Postman to call the delete method using a DELETE request to http://localhost:8080/grails-angular/Note. You should be able to breakpoint and see the Command object is not properly hydrating (unless your two pulls fixed it I haven't tested yet)

Comment: Also if you go to http://localhost:8080/grails-angular you should be able to see the actual app if your grunt stuff worked ok.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65110/discussion-between-jackie-and-jeff-scott-brown).

Answer (score 0):

Problem was that `request.reader.text` turns of the parsing of command objects.